# Is there a plugin for automatically adding a word or symbol after a trigger word? I.e. Like a search and replace but more like search and add?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I have a client whose business is now trademarked and would like the TM symbol to appear after the business name.

I could go in and manually add it to every instance the business name appears, but I'm wondering if there's a plugin that could find the business name and automatically add the TM symbol after each instance.

Any other suggestions, other than plugins are welcome, but I think a plugin would be easiest - just hope it exists!

Comment: Well a regular search and replace would do this. You just replace with the original term plus the addition. You don’t need anything special for search and add. Have you tried that? Please note that plugin recommendations are off topic here.

Answer (score 1):

This would run a find-and-replace on displaying the title and content field:

```
function wpse_406537_search_replace( $content ) {
    $company_name = 'The Company';

    $company_name_regex = preg_quote( $company_name, '/' );

    // Best-guess attempt at replacing company name that doesn't yet have ™️
    // e.g. The Company[space]
    // e.g. The Company.
    // e.g. The Company,
    // e.g. The Company[end of string]
    $content = preg_replace(
        "/$company_name_regex( |\.|,|\$)/i",
        "$company_name™️",
        $content
    );

    return $content;
}

add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpse_406537_search_replace' );
add_filter( 'the_title', 'wpse_406537_search_replace' );
```